# knockout mapping not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have written a simple sample of code using Knockout. I have recently started using knockout, so I think I have not understood something.

I have added the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/mEp2g/6/

I would have expected the data to appear in the table, but it does not.

```
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

When I run it on IE10, it also complains that "fromJS" is undefined.
If I run it on Firefox, it gives no error, but does not show the data.

Please can anyone help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mEp2g/10/

The error was on this line:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach:viewModel">
```

should be:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach:$data">
```

If you do `foreach:viewModel`, knockout will look for a property called viewModel on you viewModel.

Also added ko.mapping to the fiddle, are you sure you are loading the ko.mapping lib correctly in IE 10 ?

Comment: Thanks. It works now on fiddle. What do you mean by loading ko.mapping lib in IE10? How do you load ko.mapping js in IE10?

Comment: I mean, is the library loaded correctly as a script. If you write ko.mapping in the console, do you get an an error or undefined, or do you get an object? If you don't get an object, the library is not loaded correctly

Comment: Thanks pax, its loading fine on IE10 now. I was missing the reference to mapping js from CDN. I have now copied this code in my project. Its working fine in IE10, but does not work on IE8. It cannot find mapping object. I have added the following references at the top of the page:     <script src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>

Comment: No problem, remember to accept/upvote the answer if it was useful. IE8 has some quirks(i.e. the console object exists only if the debug console is open). Try opening the console and running your code again. Is it working?

Comment: I have got this code in my MVC web application now. The webpage does not show data on IE8. Do you mean I should add reference to <script src="~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.debug.js"></script>?

Comment: And do you get anything in the IE8 console, like errors or messages?

Comment: yes I get 'mapping' is null or undefined. for some reason ko mapping js is not getting loaded/ or is not recognised

Comment: You could try to make a combined/minified file of both standard ko and ko.mapping, so as to have only one request from IE8. I think something like this happened to me once and this was the solution.